# Random number value doesn't show in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I click on the generate button it shows undefined, it's supposed to get a unique id number. from the guidGenerator. Something is wrong with the generateID function where the guidGenerator is but i'm not sure what to put there. I need the value that the guidGenerator returns. If i do document.write(guidGenerator) alone it will display the code but not in the textbox.

```
    function guidGenerator() {
      var S4 = function() {
        return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
      };
      return (S4()+S4()+S4());
    }

    function generateID(guidGenerator) {
      var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("generateidtxt");
      TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + guidGenerator;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How are you calling the `generateID` function? Right now you have a parameter `guidGenerator`, so when you use that identifier inside the function it will use the value of the parameter, not the function `guidGenerator` that you defined earlier.

Comment: Show how you're calling `generateID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function

```
TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + guidGenerator(); // added parentheses
```

**EDIT**

Agreed with @Ian that this isn't the only problem. I'll be able to say more when I see how you call `generateID` but maybe you want to remove the function parameter and call `guidGenerator` as showed above.

Comment: Wouldn't work. The parameter is called `guidGenerator`, which is probably `undefined` and does nothing

Comment: @Ian he probably just needs to remove to argument `guidGenerator`.

Comment: @basilikum Agreed, it just needed to be said, because simply adding `()` wouldn't work immediately.